# jfrog-cli + github: download latest artifacts from specific (main/default) branch

Tags: github, artifactory

We would like to run scheduled builds on github using artifacts stored in Artifactory, from github.

I can download the "latest" artifacts using `jf rt dl --build "Action Name" --flat` but this will also download from feature branches, whoever build last. However, we want to specifically only use the latest artifacts from the main branch only.

Is there a (proper) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have mixed builds and branches.

- A branch is a Git phrase that refers to a commit.
- A build is a CI word for a sequence of instructions that builds and publishes code to Artifactory.

If the build name in your build contained the branch name, it would immediately meet your need. Take, for example, the following upload command:

```bash
jf rt upload a.txt generic-local/ --build-name="<build-name>-<branch>" --build-number="<build-number>"
```

Artifactory, as far as I know, does not now support downloading artifacts using VCS information.

Comment: That is indeed what we started doing. However, we don't use the branch name because by convention it contains a foward slash (feature/topic) and that breaks Artifactories search for 'number' so we just used the git-sha instead :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a different version range for `main` than PR builds, then you could filter on the `main` build version range.
This is difficult to do with maven as it has such a simple versioning scheme.

Another option is to push your `main` builds to a different repo so the PR/unmerged artifacts are not co-mingled with the `main` ones.